# Java static methods overriding and interfaces

Tags: java, methods, static, overriding

I have an A interface with a method `getT()`, `abstract B class` with method `getS()` and `class C` that extends `B class` which `implements A interface`. I'm overriding methods from `A` interface and `B` superclass inside the `C` subclass. Then in the `main` method I instantiate the `C` class to be typeo if `A` like this: `A obj = new C();` I'am able to call the `getT()` from `obj`, but can't call `getS()` method. How can I call `getS()` method from `obj`, but I can't change the type of `obj`, it has to be `A`. Here is the code:

**Interface A :**

```
public interface A {
    public String getT();
}
```

**Abstract class B :**

```
public abstract class B implements A {
    public abstract String getS();
}
```

**subclass C :**

```
public class C extends B {

    @Override
    public String getT() {
        System.out.println("method getT() from C class");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getS() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

And the main method inside of the T class :

```
public class T {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A obj = new C();
        obj.getT();
    }

}
```

Comment: Where are these "static methods"? Where is this "overriding"?

Answer (score 1):

With a reference variable of type `A`, you cannot call `getS()`, because it could be any type that implements `A`, say, `AImplementer`, that doesn't extend from `B`.  Any `A` object doesn't necessarily have a `getS()` method.  It's only guaranteed to have a `getT()` method.

If `obj` has to be a type `A` and you need to call `getS()`, then include the `getS()` method in the definition of the `A` interface:

```
public interface A {
    public String getT();
    public String getS(); // Add this line.
}
```

Then `B` is still an `A`, and you can call `getS()` on an `A` reference variable.

By the way, I don't see any `static` methods in your code.  Static methods cannot be overridden.

Comment: Sorry, I ment abstract method

Answer (score 1):

To gain access to the method you will need to downcast obj to B.

So you could have:

`((B)obj).getS();`

Downcasting: http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/java-questions/downcasting-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

the type class of obj is A, but A hasn't method getS() so you can't call in the main method.
obj must be class B or class C.